# Integral with an exponential function with square root as an exponent

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula

How can I solve this integral? I worry about the exponential function, normally I would just use the residue theorem but here I worry it is not possible to use it.

$$\LARGE\oint\frac{e^{i\sqrt{\frac1z+z+1}}}{-z^2+z+1} dz$$

The contour is a unit circle $|z|=1$. Any help would be appreciated.